# How mysql reads and returns large data with SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, innodb

How mysql doesn't go out of memory when executes SELECTs that return large amount of data?
Could you a link to any related docs?

Answer (score 0):

(Since there are several possible answers, I won't provide any links at the moment.)

**In the server:**  When needed, the query evaluation will build a temp table on disk.  That limits the query size to the available disk space.

**In the client:**  This depends on the client.  Some client APIs provide a choice between collecting the entire result set and collection a few rows at a time.  The former is likely to be limited by the available memory in the client.  PHP, for example, has a configurable max memory usage.